# Funcion JS devuelve 'undefined' al aplicar onchange sobre un 'select'

Tags: javascript, html, eventos, html-select

Llevo un varios días intentando resolver este problema y no lo consigo. Se que es muy básico, pero estoy empezando con JS y voy algo perdido.

Tengo un select creado con PHP y quiero que la función de JS me consiga los valores seleccionados con un evento onchange, pero por más que lo intento, la variable de JS me sale "undefined", cunando la consulto en la Consola. Incluso he probado de añadir un párrafo y que la función JS escribiera en el párrafo y eso lo he conseguido (lo que me hace deducir que el onchange se dispara, pero no se porque no consigo obtener el "value" de los select.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./../../template.css">
    <?php   include './../../UniversalConexio.php';
            include './../../cabecera.php';
           // include '../formato/funcions.php';?>
    <title>Game Master BFF</title>
</head>
<body>


<script>
    <?php
        $consClass = "SELECT `Id_Clase`, `Clase_Codificada` FROM `whch_class`";
        $resultado=$conexio->query($consClass) or die("No puedo realizar la consulta");
        $classArr = array();
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
            $classArr[] = $row;
        }
        $consRace = "SELECT `Id_Raza`, `Raza` FROM `whch_race`";
        $resultado=$conexio->query($consRace) or die("No puedo realizar la consulta");
        $raceArr = array();
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
            $raceArr[] = $row;
        }
        $consJob = "SELECT `Id_Oficio`, `Carrera`, `Clase`, `Humano`, `Enano`, `Halfling`, `Alto Elfo`, `Elfo Silvano` FROM `whch_job`";
        $resultado=$conexio->query($consJob) or die("No puedo realizar la consulta");
        $jobPre = array();
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
            $jobPre[] = $row;
        }
        for($iraza=1;$iraza<6;$iraza++){
            $razas = array("", "Humano", "Enano", "Halfling", "Alto Elfo", "Elfo Silvano");
            $razaindex = $razas[$iraza];
            for($iclase=1;$iclase<9;$iclase++){
                for($i=0;$i<64;$i++){
                    if($jobPre[$i]['Clase'] == $iclase && $jobPre[$i][$razaindex])
                    $jobArr[$iraza][$iclase][] = $jobPre[$i]['Id_Oficio'];
                }
            for($i=0;$i<64;$i++){
                if($jobPre[$i]['Clase'] == $iclase && $jobPre[$i][$razaindex])
                    $jobName[$iraza][$iclase][] = $jobPre[$i]['Carrera'];
            }
            }
        }
    ?>
</script>

<?php include './../../sidebarleft.html';?>
<?php //var_dump($jobName); ?>
    <div class="wrapper">

        <div class="container">     

            <h1><?php print '<img src=".\..\..\pic\MASTER_Tipo01_v02.gif" alt="Game Master BFF" title="Game Master BFF" width="205" height="200">';?></h1>

            <div class="content">
                <p>Bienvenido al proceso de creación de un nuevo personaje para WarhammerRPG. Introduce el nombre y selecciona la raza y clase de tu personaje para empezar la aventura. Si lo prefieres, puedes tirar los dados para generarlos aleatoriamente.</p>

                <?php 
                    if(isset($_POST['nombre_generado'])){
                        $Nombre = $_POST['nombre_generado'];
                    }else{
                        $Nombre = '';
                    }
                ?>

                <form action="stats.php" method="post" id="raza"> 
                    <label> Nombre:
                    <input type = "text" id = "nombrepj" name = "nombrepj" required minlength="3" value = "<?php echo $Nombre;?>"/></label>
                    
                    <label>Raza:
                    <select id = "raza" name = "raza" class = "job" onchange="selectJob();">
                        <option value = "0" >Tirar dado</option>
                          <?php foreach($raceArr as $race){
                                echo '<option value=' . $race['Id_Raza'] . '>' . $race['Raza'] . '</option>';
                            }
                            ?>
                    </select>
                    </label>
                    
                    <label>Clase:
                    <select id = "clase" name = "clase" class = "job" onchange="selectJob();">
                        <option value = "0" >Tirar dado</option>
                            <?php foreach($classArr as $clase){
                                echo '<option value=' . $clase['Id_Clase'] . '>' . $clase['Clase_Codificada'] . '</option>';
                            }
                            ?>
                    </select>
                    </label>


                    <label>Oficio:
                    <select id = "oficio" name = "oficio">
                        <option value = "0" >Tirar dado</option>
                    </select>
                    </label>
                
                    <input type = "submit" name = "Empezar" id = "Empezar" value = "Empezar"/>
                    <p id="demo"></p>
                </form>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="sidebar_right">

    </div>

<script>
function selectJob(){
    let claseCH = document.getElementById('clase').value;
    let race = document.getElementById('raza').value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + race + " and " + claseCH;   
}
</script>
</body>
<?php include './../../pie.html';
mysqli_close($conexio); ?>
</html>
```

EDITADO: añado el código entero

Comment: Agrega la función selectJob() a la pregunta. Sino no vemos donde falla. A simple vista parece correcta: https://jsfiddle.net/dn0vgq9y/

Comment: Eso que acabas de poner es porque solo has seleccionado uno de ellos, por lo tanto el otro queda undefined... ¿si ambos estan seleccionados te pasa eso?

Comment: Me pasa siempre, esten ambos seleccionados o no. De hecho, si solo selecciono "raza" me sale "undefined" y 0, que es el valor de la opción por defecto del select. Si selecciono "clase", me sale undefined y el número correspondiente de clase.

Comment: Probando tu ejemplo aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/m3gnqh4w/  a mi me funciona bien siempre.  ¿que has omitido en el código de la pregunta?  Pues algo no me cuadra.

Comment: La verdad que no lo sé, ya estaba desesperado cuando he venido a preguntar aquí. Adjunto el código entero en mi comentario inicial

Comment: El PHP no hace falta que lo intentes esconder entre `<script></script>` pues no aparece al procesarse (no tiene que ver con tu error, es solo una corrección gratuita)

Comment: Gracias, lo se. Solo me va bien para tener el código ordenado :)

Comment: Bueno, quitando toda la paja, queda tal como ya estaba antes, y me sigue saliendo bien.  No se como ayudarte, quizas deberías encerrar el `value=' . $race['Id_Raza'] . '` entre comillas así: `value="' . $race['Id_Raza'] . '"` y el otro también. Es lo único que veo mal a nivel de HTML pero al ser números seguía funcionando, aunque quizás no están bien interpretados como tales si se genera algun espacio, así que mejor encierralos entre comillas y cruza los dedos, pues si no es eso no se que más podria ser.

Comment: por cierto, en HTML los iguales van pegados a las claves y sus valores... no es que sea decisivo para tu error, es para que lo pongas bien y no te de otros errores alguna vez.  Es decir, donde pones cosas así: `<select id = "clase" name = "clase" class = "job" onchange="selectJob();">` ponlas así mejor: `<select id="clase" name="clase" class="job" onchange="selectJob();">`

Comment: Gracias por tus comentarios masterguru. Probare estos pequeños cambios que me comentas, pero es raro que si que lea correctamente la ‘clase’ y no la ‘raza’.

Comment: vale, creo que ya se porque es... estas duplicando el id="raza" en el form: `<form action="stats.php" method="post" id="raza"> ` ... cámbiale ese id para que no se repita y asunto arreglado

Comment: Correcto. Mil gracias masterguru. Era eso, podría haber estado horas repasando el código y no lo hubiera sacado.

Comment: je, suele pasar... cuando me has dicho lo de la clase y la raza se me ha encendido la bombilla y he empezado a buscar hasta que lo he visto :-)  Saludos!